# Angularjs datatables - rowCallback event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

can someone help me with rowCallback. Problem is, I have a table, and you can click anywhere on table row for open info for clicked item. On first TD I set check box. But when I check checkbox, I don't want to open info. 
Here is image for better explanation
[image]

my code

```
var vm = this;
    vm.selected = {};
    vm.selectAll = false;
    vm.toggleAll = toggleAll;
    vm.toggleOne = toggleOne;

    var titleHtml = '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showCase.selectAll" ng-click="showCase.toggleAll(showCase.selectAll, showCase.selected)">';


    function getUserTokenFromLocalStorage(localStorage) {
        var authData = [];
        for (key in localStorage) {
            if (key == "ls.authorizationData") {
                authData = localStorage[key];
            }

        }

        var jsonObj = JSON.parse(authData);
        return jsonObj.token;
    };


    var vm = this;
    vm.message = '';
    vm.someClickHandler = someClickHandler;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
        .withOption('ajax', {
            // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
            // dataSrc: 'data',
            url: serviceBase + 'test',
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'xtoken': 'Bearer ' + getUserTokenFromLocalStorage(localStorage)
            }
        })
        // or here
        .withDataProp('data')
        .withOption('processing', true)
        .withOption('serverSide', true)
        .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
        .withOption('createdRow', function(row, data, dataIndex) {
            // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive to the DT
            $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
        })
        .withOption('headerCallback', function(header) {
            if (!vm.headerCompiled) {
                // Use this headerCompiled field to only compile header once
                vm.headerCompiled = true;
                $compile(angular.element(header).contents())($scope);
            }
        })
        .withPaginationType('full_numbers')


    vm.dtColumns = vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle(titleHtml).notSortable()
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
            vm.selected[full.id] = false;
            return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showCase.selected[' + data.id + ']" ng-click="showCase.toggleOne(showCase.selected)">';
        }), //don't change state when click on this TD, only check checkbox.
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('type').withTitle('Type'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('city').withTitle('City'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('country').withTitle('Country'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('last_report_dt').withTitle('Last report'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('hardware_version').withTitle('HW version'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('rpi_image_version').withTitle('Image version'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('software_version').withTitle('Code version'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('internal_note').withTitle('Internal note'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle('Info').notSortable()
        .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
            vm.selected[full.id] = false;
            return '<a class="btn btn-default" ng-href="info/' + data.id + '">Info</a>';
        }),
    ];

    function toggleAll(selectAll, selectedItems) {
        for (var id in selectedItems) {
            if (selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                selectedItems[id] = selectAll;
            }
        }
    }

    function toggleOne(selectedItems) {
        for (var id in selectedItems) {
            if (selectedItems.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                if (!selectedItems[id]) {
                    vm.selectAll = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        vm.selectAll = true;
    }


    function someClickHandler(info) {
        vm.message = info.id;
        $location.path('info/' + info.id);

    }

    function rowCallback(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
        // Unbind first in order to avoid any duplicate handler (see https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/87)
        $('td', nRow).unbind('click');
        $('td', nRow).bind('click', function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                vm.someClickHandler(aData);
            });
        });
        return nRow;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have had this issue myself. I think your approach is a little bit backwards. You declare the `td` click handler inside `rowCallback`, just to be able to pass the id. Instead I will recommend this :

1. Add a `no-click` class to the first column to prevent click :

   ```
   DTColumnBuilder.newColumn(null).withTitle(titleHtml).notSortable()
     .withClass('no-click')
     .renderWith(function(data, type, full, meta) {
        vm.selected[full.id] = false;
        return '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="showCase.selected[' + data.id + ']" ng-click="showCase.toggleOne(showCase.selected)">';
      }),
   ```
2. Change the `rowCallback` to do nothing but injecting the `id` as attribute to the row :

   ```
   function rowCallback(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
      $(nRow).attr('data-id', aData.id);
   }
   ```
3. Create a delegated event handler on the `td`'s to replace both the event handler inside `rowCallback` and your `someClickHandler()` :

   ```
   $('#tableid').on('click', 'tbody td:not(.no-click)', function() {
     var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-id');
     vm.message = id;
     $location.path('info/' + id);
   })
   ```